# Serialize data-attributes

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization, multidimensional-array

I have a drag and drop system, and each dropped item receives three data-attributes.

- data-id
- data-order
- data-content

Now I should put these attributes into a multidimensional array. It should look like this:

data-order = "0" [data-id = "1", data-content = "blabla"];
data-order = "1" [data-id = "2", data-content = "another content"];

But I have no idea how to achieve this. Haven't working with arrays in jQuery yet.

Thanks for the help!

Here's something what I've been trying, but without succes:

```
<li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="1" data-content="blabla"></li>
<li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="2" data-content="another content"></li>

$(".send").click(function() {

    var itterate = $(".dropped");
    var data_array = new Array();

    for (var i in itterate.data()) {

        var sub_array = new Array();
        sub_array['data-order'] = i;
        sub_array['data-id'] = itterate.data()[i];
        sub_array['data-content'] = itterate.data([i]);

        data_array.push(sub_array);

    }

    var serialized = $.param(itterate.serializeArray().concat(data_array));

    $("#result").text(serialized);

});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk120Lhq/)

Comment: May I ask what exactly don't work in this code? And can you please provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: The `i` in your code was holding the values `order`, `id`, `content` not each item. You were literally looping over the data types not the `li` items themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hk120Lhq/1/

```
$(".send").click(function() {

    var data_array = new Array();
    $(".dropped").each(function(){

        var item = {};
        item['data-order'] = $(this).data('order');
        item['data-id'] = $(this).data('id');
        item['data-content'] = $(this).data('content');

        data_array.push(item);

    });
    var serialized = JSON.stringify(data_array);

    $("#result").text(serialized);

});
```

So `.each` is the same as the loop you are trying to do. I'm not sure what you were doing in your loop, but I think this is the result you wanted.

Further simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/hk120Lhq/3/

If you just want to get all the data attributes from your li and aren't sure how many there will be or what they will be called, do this: http://jsfiddle.net/hk120Lhq/4/

```
$(".send").click(function() {

    var data_array = new Array();
    $(".dropped").each(function(){
        var item = {};
        for(var i in $(this).data()){
            item[i] = $(this).data(i);
        }
        data_array.push(item);

    });
    var serialized = JSON.stringify(data_array);

    $("#result").text(serialized);

});
```

Comment: Thanks this is even more what I wanted! In fact i found an easier solution to what I needed to do: I've created 2 arrays: 1 for the days& one for the content. As the index is always the same (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)