# Find and get id attributes inside of html and replace it - jQuery

Tags: jquery, serialization

i try using this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917804/serialize-data-attributes) for serialized the attributes but not working on different case, how to find the whole attribute inside the .main div parent

```js
$(".send").click(function() {

  var data_array = new Array();
  $(".main").each(function() {
    var item = {};
    for (var i in $(this).attr('id')) {
      item[i] = $(this).attr(i);
    }
    data_array.push(item);

  });
  var serialized = JSON.stringify(data_array);

  $("#result").text(serialized);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="1" data-content="blabla" id="first">first</li>
    <li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="2" data-content="another content" id="second">second</li>
  </ul>
<labe for="input1">Name: </labe>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<button class="send">Send</button>
```

i'm trying to get all of ID inside the `<div class="main">` including input, label, and also tag `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) in your case to get all the `data-attributes` for your `.main` class. Simply using `.main` on `$.each` will not work in your case.

Edit: As per the conversation you want find the id in the .main html class and replace the existing id's with some new one. Its all working now you can click send and old id's will be stored in an array and new id's will be applied the HTML elements.

**Demo:**

```js
$(".send").click(function() {
  var data_array = []
  $(".main").each(function(index, el) {
    //store object
    var item = {};
    //find all the li in .main
    $($(el).find('li')).each(function(ind, li) {
      item["id" + ind] = $(li).attr('id') //store old li id
      $(li).attr("id", "new-li" + ind); //li change new id
    })
    //store input id
    item['id'] = $(el).find('input').attr('id') //store old id
    $(el).find('input').attr('id', 'new-input-id') //assign input new id
    //Push old id's data to array
    alert('All id`s replaced for li and input')
    data_array.push(item);
  });
  console.log(data_array)
  var serialized = JSON.stringify(data_array);
  $("#result").text(serialized);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="1" data-content="blabla" id="first">first</li>
    <li class="dropped" data-order="0" data-id="2" data-content="another content" id="second">second</li>
  </ul>
  <labe for="input1">Name: </labe>
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<button class="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your respon.. i just want to get attribute ID for input, label and tag <li> not just find children > li but for the entier elemen inside element.. please

Comment: i just adding the input inside the .main div,, the first i post but it edited and missing the input for example code

Comment: @Denis So you want to get id of li as `first` and `second` and the label text a `name:`

Comment: i want all of elemen inside the .main div get all ID please

Comment: @Denis Can you tell me what are all the `id's` in the .main div elements - Write in a comments may be

Comment: id="input1", id="first, id="second"

Comment: sorry, there are other things after successfully finding the ID, then how to replace it with other characters to change the ID value

Comment: @Denis You want to replace it with what ? some new id's - but you want to store the existing id's in an array ? Is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219600/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-denis).